# Split string received by InputStream in Java

Tags: java, string, split

Let's assume that I want to split the following string w.r.t `\n`

**Hi!\nHow are u doing\nI am good**

When I use the following code (i.e. initializing the string inside the code) :

```
String l = "Hi!\nHow are u doing\nI am good"
String[] sp = l.split("\\n");
```

It works as expected !

But if I get the input from **InputStream**  :

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String l = br.readLine();    
String[] sp = l.split("\\n");
```

it doesn't split !

Any idea why this happens ?

Comment: Can you share the output that you are getting after using the `split` method

Comment: Try using `l.split("\n")`.

Comment: What data you pass in console? If `Hi!\nHow are u doing\nI am good` then `\n` is no longer new line but simple `\\n` literal so you would need to split using `\\\\s`.

Comment: @EdgarBoda : Actually I checked it, it's exactly the same

Comment: @Pshemo : So why doesn't it work even with "\\n" if they are equal ?

Comment: @Prateek : It simply does nothing ! the result is an array with 1 element

Comment: @ArianHosseinzadeh if you have `\n` in string literal like `"a\nb"` then `\n` means new line, but lets say that you read text from file that contains `a\nb`, then `\n` stops being one char, but is sequence of two characters `'\'` and `'n'` so it is the same as `"a\\nb"` string. Your first example works because \\ in regex engine represents \ so regex is still looking for `\n` metacharacter. But if you change `\n` in your `String l` to `\\n` it will stop working because regex will not find new line `\n` but two characters '\' and 'n'.

Comment: @ArianHosseinzadeh Anyway you still didn't answer my question. What data are you writing as input in console?

Comment: @Pshemo : the input is received as : 

Hi!\nHow are u doing\nI am good

There's no enter being hit , it's only one line of input with \n in it

Comment: @ArianHosseinzadeh then string that will be read is the same as `"Hi!\\nHow are u doing\\nI am good"`. To make things work as you want you will need to replace `"\\n"` with `"\n"`. You can do it with `br.readLine().replace("\\n", "\n");`

Comment: Please try to understand the difference between '\n' in a String literal (which 'means' ENTER) and "\n" pasted in a console, which means the String consisting of the two characters '\' and 'n'..

Comment: @Pshemo : This one works , thanks

Comment: But..... WHY? do you want to do this.. IMHO, code smell http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell seems like a deeper problem with our app...

Comment: @JeroenPeeters : I'm required to do this , maybe there's a problem with the program which is giving me the input, but this is what I have to solve.

Comment: @ArianHosseinzadeh I posted my solution as answer, but I agree with Jeroen that this code smells. If it is possible you should try to change way data are send to you so it will not contain two characters `'\'` `'n'` but only one `'\n'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is that when you are passing `Hi!\nHow are u doing\nI am good` as console input then `\n` is treated as two separate characters `\` and `n` instead of one metacharacter `\n`. To make it back to `\n` you can just use `replace("\\n", "\n")` on data you get from console.

Answer (score 6):

You do not have anything to split in the second case as you are reading line. You read a line so you read until then `\n` there fore you can not split by it because it was split already by reader.

As stated in [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html)

> Reads a line of text. A line is considered to be terminated by any one of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), or a carriage return followed immediately by a linefeed.

EDIT:

For your case what you are doing wrong is probably that you copy and paste the string from the code and expect to work in the same way.

The reason why does result whole input instead of output is that out can not type `\n` and expect to be equal to line feed. The reality is that you pass two char `\` and `n`. So when you confirm it with return key value that is passed to your reading from System in is

`[H,i,!,\,n,H,o,w, ,a,r,e, ,u, ,d,o,i,n,g,\,n,I, ,a,m, ,g,o,o,d]`

where the firs string in your example is

`[H,i,!,\n,H,o,w, ,a,r,e, ,u, ,d,o,i,n,g,\n,I, ,a,m, ,g,o,o,d]`

To conclude string passed as input are treated in different manner than string defined in code. They may appear to be equal by are because `\` has special meaning in Java.

Comment: So what should I do ? it shouldn't be impossible

Comment: That depend on your goal. As you are reading from the System.in you always pass a line. There for you can not pass the `Hi!\nHow are u doing\nI am good`. You pass it line by line. Because when you type it and then confirm by return key. you string will be like `Hi!\\nHow are u doing\\nI am good\n\r`.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you should do to read all lines from the inputstream:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

String l = null;
while( (l = br.readLine()) != null) {
   System.out.println(l);
}
```

Comment: This most definitely is working! Do you really pass newLine characters to the system.in? If you simply paste the string "Hi!\nHow are u doing\nI am good" in the console then IT WILL NOT WORK! You are not pasting new-lines, but actually the two characters '\' and 'n'. Really hit enter in the console, and it should work

Comment: I know ! but I am not passing the new-line character, I am passing the  string you mentioned to the console and I don't hit the enter

Comment: But in java source code \n has special meaning. It is an escape character that is replaced with a newline. If you past "\n" in the console, then you are actually pasting the character sequence \n which is different. Your string l = "Hi!\nHow are u doing\nI am good" Does not contain the character sequence \n, but new lines. what exactly do you want? do you want to break on newlines? I guess so..

Comment: Actually I cannot change the input format because I receive it from another code which I don't have control on it, I have to solve it in my code